# Find the n highest consecutive values in a set of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some data in a table as follows:

```
FileDate  SumAmount
20150401  90.99
20150401  313
20150403  481.2
20150404  321.27
20150405  103
20150406  25
20150407  180.5
20150408  319.91
20150409  688
20150411  69
20150412  65
20150413  322
20150414  100
20150415  111.97
20150416  979.15
20150417  655.4
20150418  124
20150419  30
20150420  457
20150421  192.6
20150422  191.96
20150423  220
20150424  252.5
20150425  109.1
20150426  135.25
20150427  648.08
20150428  692
20150429  410.99
20150430  170
20150501  166.19
20150502  92
20150503  100
20150504  59
20150505  124.01
20150506  44.5
20150507  331.64
20150508  299.8
```

I am trying to devise a query that will find the highest 4 consecutive days values in the data.

Essentially, I think I need to partition by date and perform a row numbering over it but I can't seem to get the syntax right to evaluate the values.

Comment: Can you edit your post with what you've tried so far?

Comment: 4 consecutive actual days or 4 consecutive days of data 20150409 and 20150411 (no 10th) and when your data has duplicate days should we sum them together for same day? 20150401 and 20150401  as is 20150402 (no 2nd) being an example.

Comment: Looks like a "gaps and islands" problem. Try a little more searching.

Comment: `find the highest 4 consecutive days` - Did you mean the sum of SumAmount for those 4 days must be highest? And `20150401` and `20150403` is not consecutive, right?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I use -3 in the join conditions since the day itself counts as one. Let me know what you think. Also I use day of year(DY) to ensure that it's only consecutive days and so I don't have to rank the dates manually. Hope this helps!

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE(FileDate DATE ,SumAmount FLOAT);
INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  ('20150401',90.99),
        ('20150402',313),
        ('20150403',481.2),
        ('20150404',321.27),
        ('20150405',103),
        ('20150406',25),
        ('20150407',180.5),
        ('20150408',319.91),
        ('20150409',688),
        ('20150411',69),
        ('20150412',65),
        ('20150413',322),
        ('20150414',100),
        ('20150415',111.97),
        ('20150416',979.15),
        ('20150417',655.4),
        ('20150418',124),
        ('20150419',30),
        ('20150420',457),
        ('20150421',192.6),
        ('20150422',191.96),
        ('20150423',220),
        ('20150424',252.5),
        ('20150425',109.1),
        ('20150426',135.25),
        ('20150427',648.08),
        ('20150428',692),
        ('20150429',410.99),
        ('20150430',170),
        ('20150501',166.19),
        ('20150502',92),
        ('20150503',100),
        ('20150504',59),
        ('20150505',124.01),
        ('20150506',44.5),
        ('20150507',331.64),
        ('20150508',299.8);

WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT YEAR(FileDate) yr,DATEPART(DY,FileDate) dy,fileDate,SumAmount
    FROM @yourTable
),
CTE_Max_Sum
AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 A.yr,A.dy,A.FileDate,SUM(B.SumAmount) consec4DaySum
    FROM CTE A
    INNER JOIN CTE B
    ON B.dy BETWEEN A.dy - 3 AND A.dy
    AND A.yr = B.yr
    GROUP BY A.yr,A.dy,A.FileDate
    ORDER BY SUM(B.SumAmount) DESC
)

SELECT A.*,B.consec4DaySum
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE_Max_Sum B
ON A.dy BETWEEN B.dy - 3 AND B.dy
AND A.yr = B.yr
```

Results:

```
yr          dy          fileDate   SumAmount              consec4DaySum
----------- ----------- ---------- ---------------------- ----------------------
2015        117         2015-04-27 648.08                 1921.07
2015        118         2015-04-28 692                    1921.07
2015        119         2015-04-29 410.99                 1921.07
2015        120         2015-04-30 170                    1921.07
```

Comment: This does not exclude non consecutive days. If you add a further record `('20150510',30031.64)` to your test data it is included along with 7th and 8th of May, despite the 9th May being missing. It also won't work if the 4 consecutive days happen to in different years.

Comment: Sorry, I think I explained it poorly. What I meant was if there is a gap, then my query will not look at 5 or more days like you used a ranking function. Since I used day of the year, it will simply treat the missing day as having a value of 0, which I would think would be the desired results for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) for that, joining every row with its three following rows (day-wise) and summing up. This [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/205ec) sadly does not work for me, it runs on my sql server and work for you. Watch out for recursion depth, without `WHERE cte.Consecutive < 4` you quickly run into an error.

```
WITH cte (StartDate, EndDate, Consecutive, SumAmount)
AS (
    SELECT t.FileDate, t.FileDate, 1, t.SumAmount FROM dbo.table30194903 t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.StartDate, t.FileDate, cte.Consecutive + 1, cte.SumAmount + t.SumAmount
    FROM dbo.table30194903 t INNER JOIN cte ON DATEADD(DAY, 1, cte.EndDate) = t.FileDate
    WHERE cte.Consecutive < 5
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cte.Consecutive = 4
ORDER BY cte.SumAmount DESC
```

EDIT: Had two errors in my query, it summed up wrong rows and showd the last day in the series.

Comment: This works but using a cte like this to count is pretty much the same thing as a while loop. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to get this is to use an `APPLY` to get the number of records in the `n` days following each row, and then limit this to where there are `n` dates, this ensures you have consecutive days. You can then just order by the sum and select the top 1:

```
DECLARE @n INT = 4;

SELECT  TOP 1 
        FirstDate = t.FileDate,
        FourDaySum = t2.Amount
FROM    dbo.T
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  Amount = SUM(t2.SumAmount), 
                    Dates = COUNT(DISTINCT t2.FileDate)
            FROM    dbo.T AS t2
            WHERE   t2.FileDate >= t.FileDate
            AND     t2.FileDate < DATEADD(DAY, @n, t.FileDate)
        ) AS t2
WHERE   t2.Dates = @n
ORDER BY t2.Amount DESC;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57602/1)**

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an answer using a subquery, however it does take more time compared to my cte...

```
SELECT t.FileDate, SUM(s.SumAmount)
FROM dbo.table30194903 t
LEFT JOIN dbo.table30194903 s ON t.FileDate <= s.FileDate AND DATEDIFF(DAY, t.FileDate, s.FileDate) < 4 
GROUP BY t.FileDate
HAVING COUNT(s.SumAmount) = 4
ORDER BY SUM(s.SumAmount) DESC
```

Answer (score -2):

How about a simply while block and sum the values of a range of dates?

```
DECLARE @startingDate DATETIME, @searchDate DATETIME;
DECLARE  @maxSoFar INT, @sum INT, @daysRange INT;
SET @startingDate = convert(datetime, '20150401', 110)
SET @searchDate = @startingDate;
SET @daysRange = 3;
SET @maxSoFar = 0;

WHILE GETDATE()> @searchDate
BEGIN
    --PRINT @searchDate
    --PRINT DATEADD(DAY,@daysRange,@searchDate)
    SELECT @sum = SUM(SumAmount) FROM MyTable WHERE FileDate >= @searchDate AND FileDate <= DATEADD(DAY,@daysRange,@searchDate)
    IF @sum > @maxSoFar
    BEGIN
        SET @maxSoFar = @sum;
    END
    SET @searchDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@searchDate)
END
```